# Cannot Get Text to go to the Top of Page

Tags: html, css, inline

I cannot get the text for navigation to display inline and in the grey bar at the top of the page.  I am guessing there is some type of problem with my CSS.  Before I had the text included with the class="box" and the formatting was working, but the buttons wouldn't work, so I created a new div class="new" so the buttons would work.

HTML:

```
<div class="box-contents">
    <img src="../images/LOGO.png" alt="Stephen Crawford Photography Logo">
</div>

<div class="box">
</div>
<div class="new">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li class="button"><a class="button-text" href="portfolio.html">portfolio</a></li>
            <li class="button"><a class="button-text" href="../html/about.html">about</a></li>
            <li class="button"><a class="button-text" href="../html/contact.html">contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
}
.box {
    width: auto;
    height: 120px;
    background: grey;
    overflow: hidden;
    opacity: 0.85;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 3;
}
.box-contents {
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 1 !important;
    z-index: 4;
}
.new ul{
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
    font-weight: lighter;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-size: 2em;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding-top: 25px;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 100px;
    position: relative;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline;
    z-index: 99;
}
a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
}
img{
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 10px 2%;
}
.images{
    display: block;
    width: 800px;
    float: inherit;
    margin: auto;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-top: 20px;
}
```

The picture below shows the formatting issues
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most appropriate approach is to contain your logo and navigation links within your `<nav>` element. Right now they're broken out into separate elements which will cause them to stack. Recently, flexbox has become the best solution for situations like this. You'll be flexing your nav container and the unordered list inside. The margin property on the `ul` has left set to `auto`, which will push the navigation items to the right.

I've removed all of the unnecessary elements since we really just need `<nav>`. Hopefully this helps. I've included only the relevant CSS to give you a better understanding of what is happening.

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: grey;
}

nav ul {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 0 0 auto;
  list-style-type: none;
}

nav ul li {
  padding-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <img src="//placehold.it/150x50" alt="Stephen Crawford Photography Logo">
    <ul>
        <li class="button"><a class="button-text" href="portfolio.html">portfolio</a></li>
        <li class="button"><a class="button-text" href="../html/about.html">about</a></li>
        <li class="button"><a class="button-text" href="../html/contact.html">contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this css to your code and `<div class="new"> //content </div>` inside `<div class="box"> </div>` like so

```
    .new ul li{
      display: inline-block;
    }
```

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
}
.box {
    width: auto;
    height: 120px;
    background: grey;
    overflow: hidden;
    opacity: 0.85;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 3;
}
.box-contents {
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 1 !important;
    z-index: 4;
}
.new ul{
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
    font-weight: lighter;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-size: 2em;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding-top: 25px;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 100px;
    position: relative;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline;
    z-index: 99;
}

.new ul li{
  display: inline-block;
}

a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
}
img{
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 10px 2%;
}
.images{
    display: block;
    width: 800px;
    float: inherit;
    margin: auto;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<body>
            <div class="box-contents">
    <img src="../images/LOGO.png" alt="Stephen Crawford Photography Logo">
        </div>

<div class="box">
<div class="new">
   <nav>
    <ul>
    <li class="button"><a class="button-text" href="portfolio.html">portfolio</a></li>
    <li class="button"><a class="button-text" href="../html/about.html">about</a></li>
    <li class="button"><a class="button-text" href="../html/contact.html">contact</a></li>
    </ul>
   </nav>
    </div>
</div>

    <div>
        <img class="images" src="../images/DSC_7997-Edit.jpg" alt="Trevi Fountain, Rome">
        <img class="images" src="../images/DSC_1195.jpg" alt="Lake Hartwell">
        <img class="images" src="../images/DSC_7564-Edit.jpg" alt="Cinque Terre">
        <img class="images" src="../images/_DSC4277.jpg" alt="Park City">
        <img class="images" src="../images/LAC_6060.jpg" alt="Toccoa Falls">
        <img class="images" src="../images/DSC_7547-Edit.jpg" alt="Cinque Terre">
        <img class="images" src="../images/_DSC8776.jpg" alt="Campfire">
        <img class="images" src="../images/_DSC2203-Edit.jpg" alt="Milkyway">
        <img class="images" src="../images/_DSC8094-Edit.jpg" alt="Lake Hartwell">
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your div with class **new** in div with class **box**

```
<div class="box">
   <div class="new">...</div> 
</div>
```

and then change your css by replacing `.new ul` with `.new li`

```
.new li{
  ...
 }
```